# Using class methods as simple functions

Tags: python

I have a class with many methods. How can I modify my methods so that they can also be accessed directly as a function without creating object of that class? Is it possible.

Comment: Have a look at the [`@classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator.

Comment: if these methods access internal state of the object (i.e. instance variables), you can't do it.

Comment: If it makes any sense to do this they should be module level functions to begin with. Not everything has to be part of a class.

Comment: @agf: class methods get a reference to the class object, so they share state and are not quite the same as module-level functions (and have their use cases, IMHO).

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes, I know that. But if he wants them to be "accessed directly as a function" I assume he doesn't mean accessed on the class - he means what he says, called just as a function. If he has a class with many methods that make sense to be called that way -- without a reference to the class -- they should almost certainly be module level functions. He's probably not using the class for anything other than grouping functions.

Comment: @agf: Agreed. We need more context here.

Comment: If they can *also* be accessed directly, then why are they methods in the first place? What do they gain from having access to `self` that is useful and yet unnecessary?

Comment: @Karl: I don't get what you mean, exactly. Who said anything about `self`?

Comment: @NiklasB. "how can I ... without creating object of that class?" The `self` parameter is the object of that class. If you don't want to instantiate the class to use something, then it shouldn't be an instance method. The other comments explain the subtext here: very many people mistakenly think of a class as some sort of namespace. That is an abuse of the concept.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: I see what you mean now. Yes, modules should used as namespaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The methods will be "unbound" (meaning, essentially, that they have no `self` to work with). If the functions do not operate upon self, you can turn them into static-methods (which do not take a `self` first argument) and then assign them to variables to be used like functions.

Like so:

```
class MyClass(object):
    @staticmethod
    def myfunc():
        return "It works!"

myfunc = MyClass.myfunc

myfunc() # prints "It works!"
```

Essentially, you need to ask yourself "What data does my method need to (er) function?" Depending on your answer, you can use [`@staticmethod`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod) or [`@classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) or you may find that you do in fact need a `self` in which case you will need to create an object before trying to use its methods.

That final case would look something like:

```
myobj = MyClass()
del MyClass # This is a singleton class
myfunc = myobj.myfunc
```

All of that aside, if you find that all of your methods are actually staticmethods, then it's better style to refactor them out of the class into plain-old functions, which they really are already. You may have learned this "class as namespace" style from Java, but that isn't correct in Python. Python namespaces are represented by [modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: You can also use `@classmethod`, in which case the class object will be supplied as the first argument (similar to `self` for instance methods). Otherwise I don't see why this should be part of the class, and not a module-level function.

Answer (score 1):

### Unbound Methods

To create an unbound method (i.e., its first variable is'nt `self`), you can *decorate* the method using the `@staticmethod` built-in decorator. If decorators or any of that is not making sense, check out the [Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators), this [simple explanation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-cpdecor/index.html), decorators as [syntactic sugar](http://avinashv.net/2008/04/python-decorators-syntactic-sugar/) and learn [how to write a good one](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary).

```
>>> class foo(object):
...     @staticmethod
...     def bar(blah_text):
...         print "Unbound method `bar` of Class `foo`"
...         return blah_text 
...     
>>> foobar = foo.bar
>>> foobar("We are the Knights who say 'Ni'!")
Unbound method `bar` of Class `foo`
"We are the Knights who say 'Ni'!"
```

### Bound Methods

These methods are not technically 'bound', but are meant to be binded when called. You just have to point a reference to them and "Wala", you now have a reference to that method. Now you just have to pass a valid instance of that Class:

```
>>> class foo:
...     def __init__(self, bar_value = 'bar'):
 ...         self.bar_value = bar_value
...     def bar(self, blah_text):    
...         return self.bar_value + blah_text
...         
>>> bar = foo.bar
>>> bar(foo('We are the Knights who say '), "'Ni'")
"We are the Knights who say 'Ni'"
```

**Edit:** As is pointed out in the comments, it seems my usage of *'binding'* is wrong. Could somebody with knowledge of it edit/correct my post?

Comment: Did any of what I said make sense?

Comment: That's not quite correct. `foo.bar` in the *second example* is unbound, while `foo.bar` in the first example is just a normal function. The [linked blog post](http://avinashv.net/2008/04/python-decorators-syntactic-sugar/) is also not quite correct. The second example there is not equivalent to the first, after applying the decorator, `foobar` will be `None`. It would be correct if the first example used `foobar = decorator_test(foobar)`, which is in fact what the decorator does.

Comment: @NiklasB. Thanks for telling. Can you edit the post to reflect what you have just said? I thought I knew what _binding_ was, but turns out, I don't.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time right now. I also don't see what your second code sample has to do with the question, so I don't know if it'd provide actual value over the accepted answer, which already mentions `@staticmethod`.

Comment: @NiklasB. When I gave submitted the answer, it wasn't clear whether the questioner just wanted a reference to the method, or wanted to call it w/o creating an instance. Sorry

Answer (score -1):

You can call the function with the class name as a parameter, if you do not want to lose `self`:

```
class something:
    def test(self):
        print('Hello')

something.test(something)
#prints "Hello"
```

Comment: Maybe you meant `something.test(something())`? Which is equivalent to `something().test()`, so it doesn't provide much value.

Comment: I did test it. It works for me as written. I'm using Python 3, maybe that affects it?

Comment: KDavid: Yes, Python 3 doesn't differentiate between bound and unbound methods. That doesn't mean that this makes any sense, though. You could just as well give it a string or an integer instead of the class object.